# Deallocation of ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

i'm very excited about memory leaks and performance problems with iOS. Currently i've learnt that preventing leaks with getting avoid by retain cycles. I have a snippet below which is containts two viewcontrollers and i'm passing data with delegation. But when i equalized delegate var as nil, the deinit of viewcontroller was not called.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, Navigator {


func passData(data: String) {
    print("Passed data: " + data)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

deinit {
    print("deinited: " + self.description)
}

@IBAction func goSecond(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let secondVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! SecondVC
    secondVC.delegate = self
    self.present(secondVC, animated: false, completion: nil)

}


}
```

//second vc

```
import UIKit



protocol Navigator: class{
func passData(data:String)
}

class SecondVC: UIViewController {
weak var delegate:Navigator?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


@IBAction func GoFirst(_ sender: UIButton) {
   delegate?.passData(data: "I'm second VC and Passing")
   self.delegate = nil

}
}
```

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding delegates and the navigation somewhat. A delegate is something that is used to perform a task on your classes behalf ie. it delegates that function to another class.

Comment: Thanks for comment, Actually i think i know what delegation is. When i was doing research about communication patterns, the patterns that i've learned was delegation pattern and notifications / observer pattern used in communication of viewcontrollers. Also read an article on Medium about passing data by delegation.

Comment: Fair enough, just making sure. So the real reason that it isn't being deallocated here is that when you call self.present() it is putting the second VC on top of the view stack. So the first VC is still present underneath it. When you nil out your delegate property in the second VC all you are doing is removing the weak reference to it. It still exists on the stack (so you can go back to it by calling dismiss() from the second VC) If you really want to get rid of it you have to do it through self.navigationController.viewControllers() which is the array of all VC's on the stack.

Comment: Thanks. So i think the mistake i'm doing is, forgetting that still somewhere the viewcontroller has been strongly referenced to the other UIKit framework stuff (maybe your argument about view stack or the viewcontroller itself which is referenced strongly by UIView) is keeping using the viewcontroller. I think the navigation controller itself delegating the job somewhere in its library by disconnect/unwind the view from the visible stack and controller. Is it true guess?

Comment: delegate doesnt mean the whole viewcontroller instance itself, its just a pointer, set it to nil doesnt make it dealloc, since vc is still in the view stack, if you want it gone, you have to remove or replace

Comment: Solution is here stackoverflow.com/a/72713841/10632772

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misunderstood the `deinit` method's job. The deinit is supposed to be called when the instance of a view controller has no reference left to it. So, just simply removing the references of the properties of a view controller doesn't do the whole job.

And you have a misconception of making `self.delegate = nil` in your `SecondVC`. This should have been done in your first `ViewController`.

To make sense of everything, I've done a sample project where you can learn *how deinits work*. The main code goes here:

**First View Controller**

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, Navigator {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    deinit {
        print("First view controller's deinit called")
    }

    func passData(data: String) {
        print("In First view controller: \(data)")
    }

    @IBAction func gotoSecond(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let viewcontroller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        viewcontroller.delegate = self
        show(viewcontroller, sender: self)
    }

}
```

**Second View Controller**

```
protocol Navigator {
    func passData(data:String)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate:Navigator?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    deinit {
        print("Second view controller's deinit called")
    }

    @IBAction func closeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.passData(data: "Delegation from second view controller")
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)  //when this line executes, the instance of this class is de-referenced. This makes the call to deinit method of this class.
    }
}
```

So, when `dismiss` happens for second view controller, the reference count goes to `0` for second view controller and this does the job for calling `deinit` method of second view controller.

> But you technically don't call the `deinit` of the first view
>   controller as you don't actually de-reference the first view
>   controller.

You can find the whole project [here](https://bitbucket.org/m-i-n/deinit-understanding).

Comment: Thank you. I've understood the weak variables but misunderstood the referencing mechanism. I 've maked sense that i'm actually making nil the pointer of the instance instead the instance itself.